# How to create and use multiple pipes within the same process with pexpect?

Tags: python, asynchronous, gdb, pexpect

I'm trying to communicate with gdb asynchronously using pexpect. If I use the same pipe to do it, the commands sent using pexpect's `sendline()` function gets mixed into each other. And if I synchronize it like this:

```
def send_command(str):
    global p
    with GDB_Engine.lock:
        p.sendline(str)
        p.expect_exact("(gdb)")
```

It'll be too slow since there'll be tons of commands coming thru. So the thing I want to do is to implement different pipes for every `send_command()` block then close it when the work finishes. By this way, the text generated by `sendline()` commands won't get mixed into each other and I'll also be able to execute things asynchronously.

Comment: It's not a pexpect problem. You are running a single application and it can't take multiple independent inputs. The locking strategy is about the best you can do.